# Create digital signature with input from multiple users?

Tags: rsa, public-key, signature, multiparty-computation

Suppose that users A,B and C want to create a digital signature together. The users do not trust each other so, they need to create a signature that receives input from all of them.

The best way I though of was with RSA where each user performs a step of the key calculation:

- User A selects prime p
- User B selects prime q
- User C selects the e (By calculating N=(p*q) and so on...)

So now you have a set of keys where all users had an input.

My question: **Is there a better way ?**  (preferably with more users)

Any type of signature will work, just needs input from many users.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this? Seems like XY question.

Comment: So what you are looking for is a multi-party computation protocol that requires all parties to agree to a signature (which will then by consens create it) and where nobody can cheat?

Comment: Here is the problem: 

A,B and C need to verify the integrity of a message they will receive from X who remains ANONYMOUS (so, no public key). 

A,B and C need to create a signature (on behalf of X) and send it to X who will use it to sign the h() of the message.

For reasons I can not explain, if the signature were to be computed by just 1user, then he would had been able to impersonate X.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a threshold signature scheme: from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_cryptosystem), "it is possible to define (t,n)-threshold signature scheme, where at least t parties are required for creating a signature". Does that sound like it meets your needs?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but in threshold signatures you need ONE trusted party to generate the key which is broken down into smaller parts and given to all the users who need to work together in order to use it.

What i need is for the key to be generated with the cooperation of MANY users with no trusted party.

Comment: Do you want [strong unforgeability](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/070.pdf) against insiders? ​ ​ ​ (i.e., even when the adversary is one of ​ A,B,C ?) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer: Ideally yes but this would only be possible if A,B,C created 3 different keys. Without knowing each other's keys, they send them to X who combines them to sign the message. Then the goal is for each user to validate that the message was signed by all 3 keys without knowing the keys of the other two users.

If not possible, then I need for A,B,C to agree on a single key all together. So, you have fordability as all know the key.

Comment: Why do you want ​ "each user to" ​ not know ​ "the keys of the other two users" ? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer A valid signature needs to be made with all 3 keys and the only one who must be able to do it needs to be X. To validate the signature, A,B,C need to verify that it was made with all 3 keys but they only know what their own key is.

Comment: What stops the adversary from simply replacing those other keys with keys generated by the adversary? ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer  Keys are sent individually in encrypted form and can not be intercepted.

Comment: Do A,B,C get to see the ciphertexts for the other keys? ​ If no, then that's not enough, since for example, C doesn't know A's key and doesn't know B's key. ​ ​ ​ ​